# How to delete linked list with input value as parameter in java

Tags: java

I have problem with delete the linked list because it should have value as parameter. So if I didnt input 1 and 5 it still delete the linked list but in the last two data inside linked list.

here my code :

```
public class Set {

    private static class Node {

        private Integer val;
        private Node next;
    }
    Node node;

    public void remove(Integer val) {

    Node curr = node;

    while (curr.next != null && curr.val != val) {
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    if (curr == node) {
        node = curr.next;
    } else {
        Node curr2 = node;
        while (curr2.next != curr) {
            curr2 = curr2.next;
        }
        curr2.next = curr.next;
    }
    }
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set A = new Set();
    Set B = new Set();

    A.remove(1);
    A.remove(5);

    B.remove(1);
    B.remove(5);
}
```

Comment: where is the linked list? and why do use Set for your class name, given that it is a widely used class of the java api? why do you want to remove something which was not added??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel again... try to use one of standard java Collection implementation. E.g.: [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
[#remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28int%29)

[#remove(Object object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

[#removeFirstOccurence(Object object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeFirstOccurrence%28java.lang.Object%29)

If its not "exactly" what you need, then extends it for your needs. Rather than create your own class from scratch.

Try to play a little bit with int/Integer:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
Integer one = new Integer(1);
Integer two = new Integer(2);
Integer three = new Integer(3);

List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list.add(one);
list.add(two);
list.add(three);
list.add(new Integer(1));
list.add(new Integer(2));
list.add(new Integer(3));

System.out.println("Full list: " + list);
```

// Full list: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

```
list.remove(1);
System.out.println("remove(1) by index -> item on index 1: " + list);
```

// remove(1) by index -> item on index 1: [1, 3, 1, 2, 3]

```
list.remove(one);
System.out.println("remove(one) by object -> item equals to object reference 'one' (first by index): " + list);
```

// remove(one) by object -> item equals to object reference 'one' (first by index): [3, 1, 2, 3]

```
list.remove(new Integer(1));
System.out.println("remove(new Integer(1)) by object -> item equals to automatically downcasted Integer with value 1: " + list);
```

// remove(new Integer(1)) by object -> item equals to automatically downcasted Integer with value 1: [3, 2, 3]
}

Comment: yeah because I must use underlying linked list as a structure to implement this method...so i want remove like A.remove(1); A.remove(5) if i input 1 5 10 15 1 and 5 will be deleted but if i input 10 15 20 30 it will delete 20 and 30..i dont know why...because remove function was called twice

Comment: Check documentation difference between: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28int%29 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

Why are you implementing your own Linked List rather than just using the lists from the Collections API?

Your "Set" class is actually a "List" class, sets have different behavior to lists.

Your list doesn't get any values put into it.

Why not remember your previous node as you scan through the first time rather than re-scanning again to find the previous one.

Beyond that I'm not clear on what the actual problem is here. Can you be more clear about the exact behavior you are getting and the behavior you are expecting to get?

Edit to add:

Even if no matching node is found you still go ahead and do the remove - so when you do a remove for an element that is not found then the last item in the list will be removed.

Comment: yeah because I must use underlying linked list as a structure to implement this method...so i want remove like A.remove(1); A.remove(5) if i input 1 5 10 15 1 and 5 will be deleted but if i input 10 15 20 30 it will delete 20 and 30..i dont know why...because remove function was called twice

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer to explain why that's happening.